# Nuxtjs how to configure webpack for npm run generate when importing css file for component?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Note: I know almost no webpack, but have been googling trying to figure this out.

I have a simple vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="d-appendix">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style src='../styles/d-appendix.css'>
</style>
```

and the css file is:
and the css

```css
.d-appendix {
  contain: layout style;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 48px;
}

.d-appendix h3 {
  grid-column: page-start / text-start;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}

.d-appendix h3 + * {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.d-appendix ol {
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .d-appendix ol {
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
  }
}

.d-appendix li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.d-appendix a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.d-appendix > * {
  grid-column: text;
}

.d-appendix > .d-footnote-list,
.d-appendix > .d-citation-list,
.d-appendix > .distill-appendix {
  grid-column: screen;
}
```

running `npm run generate` throws:

```
ERROR in ./styles/d-appendix.css?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./styles/d-appendix.css?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: CSS Loader Invalid Options

options should NOT have additional properties

    at validateOptions (/Users/sumner/Projects/vdistill/frontend/node_modules/css-loader/node_modules/schema-utils/src/validateOptions.js:32:11)
    at Object.loader (/Users/sumner/Projects/vdistill/frontend/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:44:28)
 @ ./styles/d-appendix.css?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./styles/d-appendix.css?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&) 4:14-253
 @ ./styles/d-appendix.css?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./components/DAppendix.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/index.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js
```

I did some googles, and tried changing `nuxt.config.js` to have

```js
// inside build
  extend (config, ctx) {
       config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
          import: true,
          importLoaders: true,
        }
      })
```

This now gives me:

```
ERROR in ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | exports = module.exports = require("../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js")(false);
    | ^
  2 | // Module
  3 | exports.push([module.id, "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n.nuxt-progress {\n  position: fixed;\n  top: 0px;\n  left: 0px;\n  right: 0px;\n  height: 2px;\n  width: 0%;\n  opacity: 1;\n  transition: width 0.1s, opacity 0.4s;\n  background-color: #fff;\n  z-index: 999999;\n}\n\n.nuxt-progress.nuxt-progress-notransition {\n  transition: none;\n}\n\n.nuxt-progress-failed {\n  background-color: red;\n}\n", ""]);
```

How do I get my css import to work?

[Repo](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/vdistill)

Comment: odd error, I think its to do with `<style src='../styles/d-appendix.css'>` try an import  `<style>@import '../styles/d-appendix.css'</style>`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I used `src` as I also use the components for rollup. Import doesn't work with rollup in my experience

Comment: `export default { css :[ '../styles/d-appendix.css']
}` this is how you import css.

Comment: @Eldar so it is the fact that it is an empty script?

Comment: Accidentally hit enter sorry.

Comment: @Eldar will that work with rollup?

Comment: Or you import like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208205/how-to-import-css-modules-correctly-with-nuxt)

Comment: @Eldar the first solution (export css) did not work

Comment: @Eldar I do not understand the second.

Comment: It is importing it like a module. Assigns a name to it and returns it in a computed function called styles

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/example-global-css-7nt8y?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) example for that. It seems the links contains outdated import syntax. And you don't need to configure Nuxt to load css. It has already configured to load css by default.

All you have to do is like below :

```
<script>
import foo from "../css/custom.css";
export default {
computed: {
    styles() {
      return foo
    }
  }
}
</script>
```